# How to position image so it overlaps the background image

Tags: html, css

Will i need javascript? or html css is enough, if so, should i use position or what properties to do that?

If I did not describe clearly then the picture may help to demonstrate

[image: If I did not describe clearly then the picture may help to demonstrate]

Comment: In the picture you provided, which image are you trying to place in between what? Please describe the problem a little more.

Comment: Do you mean the profile image? You want to know how to position it so it overlaps the background image?

Comment: @flowstoneknight profile image   and its solved now!

Comment: @Lee yeah overlaps!!

Comment: Ah okay, I see you've got your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position relative` on the top div and `Position absolute` on the img

## [DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/kfx4s1dd/)

[image]

MARKUP:

```
<section>
    <article>
        <figure></figure>
    </article>
    <article></article>
</section>
```

STYLE:

```
*{box-sizing:border-box; padding: 0; margin:0;}
section{
    width:480px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

article{
   min-height:320px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
}
figure{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-40px;
    right:10px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px; 
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do further demonstrate kougiland's point, here is a fiddle that has what you want:

```
.header{
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   background: #000;
   position: relative;
}

.image{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
   right: 50px;
   bottom: -50px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ws2objpr/)